# Wrting a SQL query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this so far:

```
var query = (from g in this.Context.Groups
    where g.ID == groupID &&
          g.TaxId == groupTaxId
    select g.Group_K);
```

Then the `SQL` query I want to add is this:

```
select zipCode from ADDRESSES where ADDRESS_K in 
(select ADDRESS_K from GROUPADDRESS 
       where GROUP_K = "is in Group_K found above "
       and address_type = "address type variable I pass into this method"
       and ACTIVE = 1)
```

I can't figure it out how to add a new `LINQ` query or update the one I have to account for the new `SQL` I am trying to add.  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?

```
        var group_key = (from g in this.Context.Groups
            where g.ID == groupID
                  && g.TaxId == groupTaxId
            select g.Group_K);

        var query = (from a in this.Context.Addresses
            join ga in this.Context.GroupAddress on a.Address_K equals ga.Address_K
            where (group_key.Contains(ga.Group_K) && a.ZipCode == "whatever passed from method" && ga.Address_Type == "whatever passed from your method")
            select a);
```

Answer (score 0):

`IN` statement is equivalent to `Contains` method call in LINQ to Entities:

```
var query = from a in this.Context.Addresses
            where (from g in this.Context.Groups
                   where g.ID == groupID && g.TaxId == groupTaxId
                   select g.Group_K).Contains(a.Address_K);
            select a.ZipCode;
```

You could also rewrite your query to use `JOIN` instead of nested queries:

```
var query = from a in this.Context.Addresses
            join g in this.Context.Groups on a.Address_K equals g.Group_K
            where g.ID == groupID && g.TaxId == groupTaxId
            select a.ZipCode;
```

Comment: Thanks, Yep I was thinking there should be a way to JOIN them in one query. cool.

Comment: and "Contains" is a "LIKE" in SQL? So I don't need to call a .Trim().ToUpper() on the strings I pass to Contains"

Comment: It depends what is the object you call it on. `Contains` on `string` will end up as `LIKE`, but `Contains` on a collection will make it to the SQL as `IN` clause.

Comment: oh wait! my SQL has GroupAddress table which is the bridge table between Groups and Address table so GroupAddress table is the one that has Group_K and Address_K so the join you wrote won't work, those are not the same keys.  Thanks for re-thinking about it in advance :)